# Index(Match and XLOOKUP/VLOOKUP not working because I use SUBSTITUTE on matching text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, xlookup

I am trying to pull the corresponding vendor value from Table 1 (Vendors) to Table 2 (Client Totals). This is a simple INDEX(MATCH or XLOOKUP but I am running into problems.

Table 2 contains totals from a pivot table, pulled using the following formula:
=filter(A1:D,search("Total",A1:A)>1).
The text resulting text is "Client 1 Total" "Client 2 Total" etc. To remove the "Total" from the text, I used a SUBSTITUTE formula:
=If(H8<>"Grand Total",SUBSTITUTE(H8,"Total",""),"Grand Total").
This gives me the desired result.

However, INDEX(MATCH and XLOOKUP are not reading the text correctly now that I have used a SUBSTITUTE formula. "Text not found in lookup evaluation."

I have tried adding another column to convert it to text using =TEXT(cell,0) but no dice. I have also tried making both columns plain text. I have trimmed whitespace from cells. I am certain I am using INDEX(MATCH and VLOOKUP correctly. It is the substitute formula causing problems!

**TABLE 1 - VENDORS** - Vendor prices per Client

| Client | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | $10 |
| Client 2 | $20 |

**TABLE 2 - CLIENT TOTALS** - Client column used SUBSTITUTE to remove "Total" from Client name. I want to pull price from Table 1 to Table 2.

| Client | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 |  |
| Client 2 |  |

Any alternatives or workarounds to this issue?